# Find duplicate rows based on date in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two Tables. T1 and T2.

**Table T1:**

```
dno     jno
1       a
1       b
1       c
```

**Table T2:**

```
jno     date
a       2017
b       2017
c       2016
```

I want to get duplicate rows in T1 based on date in T2. If I do this:

```
select T1.dno, count(T1.dno) count from T1 left join T2 on T1.jno = T2.jno
group by T1.dno
having date=2017
```

`T1.dno` gets grouped together and I can't find out the duplicates.

Expected Output:

```
dno count
1   2
```

Any tips?

Comment: what is your expected result ? Can you post that

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Updated

Comment: You say: _"T1.rno gets grouped together and I can't find out the duplicates."_. Q: In expected results, how do you identify the duplicates?

Comment: @MYGz Can you check your expected output again, it doesn't match your sample data

Comment: 1 sec let me update the question. I might have simplified it too much.

Comment: It looks even less clear then before :D

Comment: I would suggest to add some more example data, or try to explain better your final target. It is very hard for us to get a pattern from only 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
your question looks so vague and i may not have understood it.

But anyway, based on your expected output your first query was ok, just change the `HAVING` clause and make it a `WHERE` clause

```
select T1.dno, count(T1.dno) count
from T1
left join T2 on T1.jno = T2.jno
WHERE T2.DATE = 2017
group by T1.dno
```

Comment: Updated the question. Kindly check now.

Comment: @MYGz well, check the edit. I hope i got the point.

Comment: Thanks. This works.

Answer (score 0):

The below query should help you

```
select rno, count(date) cnt
from t2
where t2.rno in (select T1.rno from T1)
group by rno
having count(date) > 1 -- this will get you the duplicate records
```

Comment: Updated the question. Kindly check now.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output can be gotten by the following query:

```
SELECT t1.dno, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.date) AS count
FROM T1 t1
LEFT JOIN T2 t2
    ON t1.jno = t2.jno
GROUP BY t1.dno;
```

But it is not clear what role `T1` plays here.

Comment: Updated the question. Kindly check now.

Comment: based on your edit, this answer gives you expected output

Comment: @B3S This question is so vague, it would not surprise me if the expected answer looks nothing like anything we have written here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this. It'll give you the the year and how many records were returned for that year.

```
select t1.dno,t2.date,count(t2.date) 
from t1 inner join t2 on t2.jno = t1.jno
group by t1.dno,t2.date
having count(t2.date) >1
```